# Resizing HTML elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following code :

```
<title>Waypoints in directions</title>
<style>
  html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
  #map-canvas{
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
  .boxsizingBorder {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div><input id="navigate" type="button" value="Navigate" onClick="calcRoute()" style="width:100%;height:10%;" /></div>

</body>
```

I'm trying to make the map-canvas div to be 90% of the whole page and the navigation button 10% of all the page , but no matter what i write in the height of the navigation button it doesn't change ,
why ?
but if change its height to something with px , like 70px it changes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use percentage based measurements, the parent element must have a defined height. Currently, your navigate button is contained within a div which does not have a set height, so it does not know what to base the 10% height on. If you give the containing div a height it will work.

```
<div style="height:200px;"><input id="navigate" type="button" value="Navigate" onClick="calcRoute()" style="width:100%;height:30%;" /></div>
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5dvwymxv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove wrapper div

```
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    <input id="navigate" type="button" value="Navigate" onClick="calcRoute()" style="width:100%;height:10%;" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For one you need to add a height to the button's parent so it can inherit something. You can also use

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

And then style the button as you please

example: http://jsfiddle.net/59cpxL3n/4/